How to Pass Data Among Steps in a java Spring Batch Application
I have a spring batch project to read two txt files (Cyties and Histories) in two different steps. I use the ItemsReaders, everything is fine, I can even write them together in a single new file in json format (which is the desired goal). but before writing them I need to compare them in items processor so that when there is a match. each city is written followed by its history. I'm trying to set up a jobExecutionContext in order to retrieve my historical list from my process1 and compare them to my city list in my process2. It was impossible for me to achieve this. Can you help me find the problem?
//this is my batchCongig
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

  @Bean
  DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql").generateUniqueName(
        true).build();
  }

  @Bean
  PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTransactionManager(ds);
  }

  @Bean
  public Job runjob(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager txManager)
      throws Exception {
    return new JobBuilder("runJob", jobRepository)
        .start(step1(jobRepository, txManager))
        .next(step2(jobRepository, txManager))
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager txManager)
      throws Exception {
    return new StepBuilder("step1")
        .repository(jobRepository)
        .<Historique,Historique>chunk(100)
        .reader(readerStep1())
        .processor(processStep1())
        .writer(writerStep1())
        .listener(promotionListener())
        .transactionManager(txManager)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListener() {
    ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
    listener.setKeys(new String[]{"histories"});
    return listener;
  }

  @Bean
  public Step step2(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager txManager)
      throws Exception {
    return  new StepBuilder("step1")
        .repository(jobRepository)
        .<City,City>chunk(100)
        .reader(readerStep2())
        .processor(processStep2())
        .writer(writerStep2())
        .transactionManager(txManager)
        .build();
  }

//
//  @Bean
//  public Step stepCity(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager txManager)
//      throws Exception {
//    return new StepBuilder("stepCity")
//        .repository(jobRepository)
//        .<City, City>chunk(100)
//        .reader(readerCity())
//        .processor(processorCity())
//        .writer(writerCity())
//        .transactionManager(txManager).build();
//  }

  @Bean
  public ItemReader<Historique> readerStep1()
      throws Exception {
    FlatFileItemReader<Historique> readerStep1 = new FlatFileItemReader<Historique>();
    readerStep1.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {{
      setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
        setNames(new String[]{"mod", "date_eff", "typecom_av", "com_av", "tncc_av", "ncc_av", "nccenr_av", "libelle_av", "typecom_ap", "com_ap", "tncc_ap", "ncc_ap",
                             "nccenr_ap", "libelle_ap"});
      }});
      setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Historique>() {{
        setTargetType(Historique.class);
      }});
    }});
    readerStep1.setResource(new ClassPathResource("documents/HistoriqueCities.txt"));
    return readerStep1;
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemReader<City> readerStep2()
      throws Exception {
    FlatFileItemReader<City> readerStep2 = new FlatFileItemReader<City>();
    readerStep2.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {{
      setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
        setNames(new String[]{"typecom", "com", "reg", "dep", "arr", "tncc", "ncc", "nccenr", "libelle", "can", "comparent"});
      }});
      setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<City>() {{
        setTargetType(City.class);
      }});
    }});
    readerStep2.setResource(new ClassPathResource("documents/Cities.txt"));
    return readerStep2;
  }

  @Bean
  public ProcessStep1 processStep1() {
    return new ProcessStep1();
  }

  @Bean
  public ProcessStep2 processStep2() {
    return new ProcessStep2() {
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemWriter<Historique> writerStep1() {
    JsonFileItemWriter<Historique> writerStep1 = new JsonFileItemWriter<>(new FileSystemResource("src/main/java/output/testStep.json"),
        new JsonObjectMarshaller<Historique>() {
          @Override
          public String marshal(Historique object) {
            try {
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
              return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            }
            catch(JsonProcessingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return null;
            }
          }
        }) {
      @Override
      public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext)
          throws ItemStreamException {
        super.open(executionContext);
        try {
          getOutputState().write("[{Historique: }");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    };
    writerStep1.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/java/output/testStep.json"));
    writerStep1.setJsonObjectMarshaller(new JsonObjectMarshaller<Historique>() {

      @Override
      public String marshal(Historique historique) {
        Map<String, String> mapStory = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        mapStory.put("parent", historique.getCom_av());
        mapStory.put("typeMod", historique.getTypecom_av());
        mapStory.put("typeModNumber", historique.getMod());
        mapStory.put("oldLabel", historique.getLibelle_ap());
        mapStory.put("Label", historique.getLibelle_av());
        mapStory.put("date_eff", historique.getDate_eff());
        List<ProcessStep1> historiqueList = new ArrayList<>();


        return mapStory.toString();
      }
    });
    return writerStep1;

  }

  @Bean
  public ItemWriter<City> writerStep2() {
    JsonFileItemWriter<City> writerStep2 = new JsonFileItemWriter<>(new FileSystemResource("src/main/java/output/testStep.json"),
        new JsonObjectMarshaller<City>() {
          @Override
          public String marshal(City object) {
            try {
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
              return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            }
            catch(JsonProcessingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return null;
            }
          }
        }) {

      @Override
      public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext)
          throws ItemStreamException {
        super.open(executionContext);
        try {
          getOutputState().write("[{City: }");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    };
    writerStep2.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/java/output/testStep.json"));
    writerStep2.setAppendAllowed(true);
    writerStep2.setJsonObjectMarshaller(new JsonObjectMarshaller<City>() {
      @Override
      public String marshal(City city) {
        Map<String, String> mapCity = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        mapCity.put("parent", city.getCom());
        mapCity.put("typeMod", city.getTypecom());
        mapCity.put("typeModNumber", city.getLibelle());
        mapCity.put("oldLabel", city.getComparent());
        mapCity.put("Label", city.getCountry());
        System.out.println(mapCity.toString() + "test");
        return mapCity.toString();

      }
    });
    return writerStep2;
  }

// now my ProcessStep1
@Component
public class ProcessStep1 implements ItemProcessor<Historique, Historique>, StepExecutionListener {

  private DataHolder dataHolder;
  private ChunkContext chunkContext;

  @Override
  public Historique process(Historique historique) throws Exception {

    ExecutionContext executionContext = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();

    List<Historique> historiqueList = new ArrayList<>();
    executionContext.put("histories", historiqueList);
    return historique;
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    StepExecutionListener.super.beforeStep(stepExecution);
    dataHolder = new DataHolder();
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("histories", dataHolder);

  }
  @Override
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    DataHolder dataHolder = (DataHolder) stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("histories");
    return StepExecutionListener.super.afterStep(stepExecution);
  }
}


//and my processStep2
@Component
public class ProcessStep2 implements ItemProcessor<City, City>, StepExecutionListener {

  private DataHolder dataHolder;
  private ChunkContext chunkContext;

  @Override
  public City process(City city) throws Exception {
    ExecutionContext executionContext = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
    List<Historique> historiqueList = (List<Historique>) executionContext.get("histories");
    if(historiqueList == null) {
      historiqueList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    city.setHistoriqueList(historiqueList);

return city;
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    StepExecutionListener.super.beforeStep(stepExecution);
    DataHolder dataHolder = (DataHolder) stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("histories");
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("cities", dataHolder);
  }
  @Override
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    return StepExecutionListener.super.afterStep(stepExecution);}

  }

//I try to keep my data in memory in a DataHolder class to be able to pass them because I don't use a database
@Component
public class DataHolder implements Serializable {
  private Map<String, Object> dataMap;

  public DataHolder() {
    dataMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getDataMap() {
    return dataMap;
  }

  public void setDataMap(Map<String, Object> dataMap) {
    this.dataMap = dataMap;
  }

I relied on this doc to code my app:
https://medium.com/@umutaskin/how-to-pass-data-among-steps-in-a-spring-batch-application-3568ae6f63d6
